# display and change image using timer JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 images in an array

```
images = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"]
```

I want a JavaScript script that displays image1 when the page loads, but also so that for every 3 seconds the next image in the array is displayed, hence replacing the previous image. However when it reached the image4, the reverts back to image1.

EDIT: As someone asked, here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<body onload = "myFunction()">
<img src ="image1.png" id = "target" >
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    var images = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png",image4.png"];
    function myFunction() {
       counter += 1
       if (counter > 4) {
           counter = 0
       }
       target = document.getElementById ("target").src = images[counter]
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If any errors are found please notify me. I have tried setInterval before however it just gave me image1 when the page loads. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tired googling for any plugins like [SlidesJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/)

Comment: Please share what you have tried. If you have not, search for `setInterval` in JavaScript...

Comment: This question does not show any research effort..

Comment: edited it and shown what i've got so far. I tried using setInterval however it gave me nothing except image1 when the page loads.

Comment: show your `setInterval` code

Comment: the first images comes from `onload` but you need to call it every 3 seconds and for this you need to use `setInterval` and there can be the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like why people downvote immediately rather than suggesting a solution. Have you tried a slideshow?! No maybe he doesn't want to use someone else's code or maybe he is not allowed to in his project.

Anyway, first you have a quote error in your image array. Last item is missing a quote.

Then you can basically add something like

```
<script language="javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];

    function myFunction() {
       counter++;
       if (counter > 4) {
           counter = 0
       }
       target = document.getElementById ("target").src = images[counter];
       setTimeout("myFunction", 3000) // 3sec

    }
    window.onLoad = function(){
       myFunction(); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really like when people put personal rants and complaints into a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Thanks, Good for you !

Comment: thank you. I understand that i was told to use a slideshow however it's true what you said. I'm not allowed to copy someone else's code. The only source i had was stackoverflow and w3schools. However i had to resort to coming onto stackoverflow as w3chools. Again thank you.